# nodejs compare Unicode file names

Tags: javascript, node.js, unicode

We're trying to compare the same file name, one is set by = operator, the other is returned by getting the file from Nodejs server after uploaded, as the following code block:

```
var name = "tên_đẹp.WAV";

// uploaded_file is the file (tên_đẹp) returned by calling an ajax function
// to get the uploaded file in uploaded_folder of a Nodejs server
ajaxUploadFile(name).done( function(e, uploaded_file) {

    if(name == uploaded_file.name) {
        return uploaded_file; // This line is never reached 
    else {
        console.log(escape(name));               // t%EAn_%u0111%u1EB9p.WAV
        console.log(escape(uploaded_file.name)); // te%u0302n_%u0111e%u0323p.WAV
    }
}
```

As you can see the result of the 2 escape commands are different.
I don't know why they use different unicode format and how can I make them use the same Unicode charset or any solution would be much appreciated?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that `"e\u0302"` and `"\u00EA"` are both visually identical. One is the specific character [U+00EA](http://www.charbase.com/00ea-unicode-latin-small-letter-e-with-circumflex) (LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH CIRCUMFLEX), and the other is `e` with the combining character [U+0302](http://www.charbase.com/0302-unicode-combining-circumflex-accent) (COMBINING CIRCUMFLEX ACCENT). You must normalize each string to a standard form first to compare them.

```
require('unorm');

var name = "tên_đẹp.WAV";

// uploaded_file is the file (tên_đẹp) returned by calling an ajax function
// to get the uploaded file in uploaded_folder of a Nodejs server
ajaxUploadFile(name).done( function(e, uploaded_file) {

    if(name.normalize() == uploaded_file.name.normalize()) {
        return uploaded_file; // This line is never reached 
    else {
        console.log(escape(name));               // t%EAn_%u0111%u1EB9p.WAV
        console.log(escape(uploaded_file.name)); // te%u0302n_%u0111e%u0323p.WAV
    }
}
```

Note that I've loaded the `unorm` module, which polyfills in the `.normalize()` method being called on the strings. This method is part of ECMA6, and in future versions of Node you will not need to load `unorm` at all.

It's impossible to say what introduced the differences there, it could have been your text editor or your browser.

Answer (score 1):

The unicode characters in uploaded_file.name are accents. `%u0302` is a diacritical mark COMBINING CIRCUMFLEX ACCENT, `%u0323` is a diactritical mark COMBINING DOT BELOW.

On the other hand, `%EA` (ê) and `%u1EB9` (ẹ) are the equivalent characters with accents integrated.

This is something handled by **Unicode equivalence** (see Wikipedia). The sequence of `e%u0302` is said to be **canonicaly equivalent** to `%EA`, and similarly for the other pair.

To handle the comparison properly in node.js, you have to normalize the strings into a canonical form (NFC or NFD). This can be achieved with [unorm](https://github.com/walling/unorm):

```
var unorm = require('unorm');
var s1 = 'êẹ';
var s2 = 'e\u0302e\u0323';
console.log(s1 == s2); // false
console.log(unorm.nfc(s1) == unorm.nfc(s2)); // true
console.log(unorm.nfd(s1) == unorm.nfd(s2)); // true
```

The choice between NFC (composed) and NFD (decomposed) should not matter in this case.

**Important:** Note that canonicalization can sometimes introduce nonobvious exploitable vulnerabilities, especially with filenames, as the OS would likely still see them as different. E.g. see this story of spotify: [Creative usernames and Spotify account hijacking](http://labs.spotify.com/2013/06/18/creative-usernames/).

Answer (score 1):

`%EA` == `ê`

`e%u0302` == `e` + `^`

These are two unicode sequences that look the same, but typed differently. If you're need to compare them, you'll have to do unicode normalization first.